# Group by State and Year using Panel data

Tags: r, group-by, panel-data

I am using the `deaths` file from chapters 5.2 and 5.3 of the Mastering Metrics data that can be found [here](http://masteringmetrics.com/resources/). I am trying to group `pop` by state and year and return the mean `pop`. I have tried several methods but when I merge the group the results do not look proper.

```
mlda <- read.dta("C:/Users/perdue/Desktop/Adv.MicroEconometrics/HA 8/deaths.dta") ## reading in my data
mlda$avg.pop <- aggregate(mlda[, 7], list(mlda$state), mean)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, avg.pop, value = list(Group.1 = c(1L,  : 
  replacement has 51 rows, data has 24786
```

Comment: The `aggregate` returns a summarised output i.e. the number of rows will be lesser than the original dataset.    You need `ave` from `base R`ie. `mlda$avg.pop <- with(mlda, ave(yourcolumn, state))`  Or use `mutate` `library(dplyr); mlda %>% group_by(state) %>% mutate(avg.pop = mean(yourcolumn))`

Comment: @akrun: Yes, that totally worked!!!